# Replication from Cassandra to JMS

Tags: cassandra, replication, change-data-capture

IS there any way we can replicate data from cassandra to external systems. Looking for some products like Goldengate (replicates from Oracle to Cassandra), but we have a requirement to capture all activities in Cassandra and replicate to let's say MQ/JMS. This is in realtime not one time export/import.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can theoretically use Cassandra's CDC (Change Data Capture) to obtain commit log segments (similarly to GoldenGate in concept), and then process the commit log segments using your own code & pushing data into MQ/JMS.

[Documentation includes pointers to relevant code](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/operating/cdc.html), but there could be multiple things that isn't very easy to handle, like, data de-duplication, fault tolerance, etc.